# Rename multiple spreadsheets macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel VBA macro that takes in multiple text files (50+), and converts them into .xlsx spreadsheets. I would like to rename these according to the original name of the file.

I've tried to use the following code, but it would only work for 1 name.

```
    Sub Rename_Files()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False

Dim k As Integer
Dim t As String
Dim x As Integer

k = Sheets.Count
x = 1

    While x <= k
        t = Sheets(x).Name
        If t = "validated_deals" Then

            Sheets(x).Name = "Clauric - Validated Deals"
            x = x + 1

        Else

            x = x + 1
        End If

    Wend

End Sub
```

Obviously I could redo the While loop for each name, but is there a quicker way to do it, using a loop. I have the names of all the files stored in a separate location, if that helps.

Comment: Where's this separate location? You have sample of current sheet names and what it needs to be changed to?

Comment: @findwindow the separate location will be within another sheet in the same book. The example is as above, in the sheet names

Comment: Load all those name in array and then inside your while condition run a loop on on that array.

Comment: Uh need more samples. How do you know how to rename each sheet?

Comment: @Nelly27281 You presume the names are in order/ignore the if condition inside while loop...

Comment: @Nelly27281 Interesting idea, but how would the array work, considering that I might have to completely rename the file? I had originally being thinking about something along the lines of relooping through the file names to check if any correspond to the files names that need to be changes, and change them accordingly. If they don't match the name, skip them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assuming you have your old sheet names in `column A` and new sheet names in `column B` on `Sheet4`,** like this:

[image]

And here is the code:

```
Sub Rename_Files()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False

    Dim k As Integer
    Dim t As String
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim arrOldNames As Variant
    Dim arrNewNames As Variant

    'GETTING THE LAST ROW FROM SHEET4
    With Sheets("Sheet4")
        LRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    'ASSUMING COL-A HOLDS OLD SHEET NAMES AND COL-B HOLDS NEW SHEET NAMES ON SHEET4
    arrOldNames = Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A2:A" & LRow).Value
    arrNewNames = Sheets("Sheet4").Range("B2:B" & LRow).Value

    k = Sheets.Count
    x = 1

    While x <= k
        t = Sheets(x).Name
        x = x + 1

        'HERE WE'LL RUN A LOOP ON ALL THE NAMES AND CHANGE THE NAME IF MATCHES
        For i = 1 To UBound(arrOldNames)
            If arrOldNames(i, 1) = t Then
                Sheets(x - 1).Name = arrNewNames(i, 1)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

    Wend

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True

End Sub
```

This sub will create two arrays, one holding old names and another holding new names. It'll run a loop on each names and if name matches, it will changes the name.

**->** Make sure you have same number of names (old and new).

Comment: lol in the time it takes to build the key, you might as well rename the sheets manually @Clauric